# Drawing vertical line in tableview cell between Dynamic Labels with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cashapelayer

I have a table view containing two labels which supports multiline and placed vertically in the container. I have fixed the distance between the both label. Texts of Label can be of two or in three lines. I am drawing a line between both the labels using `CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath`. My Problem is, I am not getting the actual width of the label, So the vertical line doesn't draw at the desired place. Here is the code I am using for the drawing. What I can think of is my lines are getting drawn first and the text of labels are getting set after that can be the issue. How can I fixed that?

**Constraints**
leading space from superview
trailing from second label
vertically in container

**TableViewCell.m**

```
@implementation KKCDDCell

{
CGFloat borderWidth;
UIBezierPath *borderPath;
}
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
 [super awakeFromNib];    
/** creating vertical line**/
[self verticalLine];
[self dottedLineWithPath:borderPath withborderWidth:borderWidth];
}

- (void)verticalLine
{
borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];    
[borderPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.labelOne.frame.origin.x +self.labelOne.frame.size.width + 10, self.frame.origin.y + 2)];
[borderPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.labelOne.frame.origin.x +self.labelOne.frame.size.width + 10,  self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height - 2)];
borderWidth = 1.0;
}


- (void)dottedLineWithPath:(UIBezierPath *)path withborderWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth
{
CAShapeLayer *shapelayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapelayer.strokeStart = 0.0;
shapelayer.strokeColor = [UIColor firstRowColor].CGColor;
shapelayer.lineWidth = borderWidth;
shapelayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
shapelayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2 ], nil];
shapelayer.path = path.CGPath;
[self.contentView.layer addSublayer:shapelayer];
}
```